# Why is "I play a video game every day?" awkward English, yet "I take a bath every day?" is standard

Tags: articles

I stumbled across this conundrum recently, and I can't particularly explain the difference.

My guess is that a bath is a one-time event whereas there are many video games that can be possibly played.

It becomes even more confusing when talking about hobbies rather than daily activities, as in:

△ "I like to take a bath." (unnatural)

○ "I like to take baths." (natural)

Comment: Because no one can play just one video game!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "I take a bath every day."

Comment: Who says it's awkward English? There's nothing awkward about "I solve a cryptic crossword every day" and that sentence has exactly the same  structure as "I play a video game every day".

Comment: @Mick I'm sorry, I was saying that "I take a bath every day." is acceptable. Even though it's the same structure, "I play a video game every day?" sounds awkward.

Comment: @BoldBen To my ears, "I solve a cryptic crossword every day." emphasizes the amount of puzzles solved - one per day (a complete action) whereas "playing video games" isn't. e.g. "I beat a video game every day." sounds marginally acceptable in the amount sense.

Comment: I like your question and would like to read a satisfying answer to it. You are correct "I play a video game every day" would only sound naturally in a specific context in which this issue is discussed. Otherwise, it is not native to the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I play a video game every day" implies that you play the same game every day (or you play a game only once). This is not a problem with "I take a bath every day", since one bath is much like another. It doesn't really matter if you bathe more than once on some days (or every day).

Comment: Not a gamer (at least not since Space Invaders was the pinnacle of gamedom), but it doesn't imply that to me. Could be any old game - same, different, doesn't matter. I'm not sure what the OP's issue is, perhaps 'I play video games every day' is what he considers the comparable sentence to "I take a bath every day".

Comment: "I play a video game every day" is something a parent would say as they don't understand it is to unwind, its for social interaction or to play multiple games.

Comment: @Mick   Phil Sweet and devc2 are correct. "Nobody plays a video game every day," unless you are talking specifically about the issue in a conversation in which this sentence would make sense. Otherwise, it is not gamer-language native speaker. What is logical, is "I play video game every day."